# Any way to use grouped_collection_select for a single model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok, so I have table called 'products' which has 'brand' and 'model' columns...

I would like to pull all models and categorize them by brand in the pull down menu by means of grouped_collection_select. Is this possible or do I need to reorganize my entire db to have brand model and submodel tables?

Thanks